# Multiple PHP scripts on AJAX url call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have no problem creating an AJAX call, but each url must at the moment be unique. I wish to contain multiple PHP functions within the same file, and specifically access one of the PHP functions with a particular AJAX call.

Using jQuery, at the moment I am passing the .data parameter with an integer specification, then using the $_GET method in the PHP file and running the proper function specified by the integer.

How can I do this better? I want to call a *specific* function amongst many in a PHP file; I do not want to have individual files for each function

Comment: You can call the same file multiple times. It just works. Even in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell you to go with the quick and dirty solution, i.e. passing a `function` param in the call, then:

```
switch($_GET['function'])
{

case 'show':    
    show();
    break;

case 'delete':
    delete();
    break;

case 'awesome':

    awesome();
    break;

}
```

But this is totally unmaintainable, because you will drown into a mess of includes, or even worse into a huge column of code you won't be able to reuse anywhere.

I advice you to get into **routing**, i.e. setting up a relationship between the URLs being pointed at, and functions being called, making use of parameters if needed [like in the second example below]:

```
/users              --> printAllUsers
/users/123          --> printUser($id)
/products/beers     --> printProducts($category)
/search             --> search()
...
```

This way you are decoupling the *routing* itself from the response generation: you can find a better overall explanation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html), then you can find a very good an thin library [here](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) you can use in your projects without relying on a whole framework.

Ah, before getting in buzzword oceans with thing like OOP, MVC, RESTful service - which all deserve to be learned of course - stick with this first concept: it was the one I really missed when I began learning all this stuff, and it was the *eureka* for me.

Comment: I have a file of PHP functions already included, and I want to simply call one of these functions asynchronously when a certain event is triggered.

Comment: @InfinitelyLoopy Go with the quick and dirty way then ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each function an `ID`, send the `AJAX` `GET` based on one `ID` and call that function with [switch](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

eg: Send `GET = 1`, or `GET = 2`

```
switch ((int)$_GET['id']) {
    case 1:
        processData();
        break;
    case 2:
        sendEmail();
        break;
    case 3:
        restoreBackup();
        break;
    // ........ and so on
}
```

Comment: It would probably be better to give them meaningful names, though. Fortunately, `switch` in PHP also allows for strings.

Comment: I meant the switch conditions — `1`, `2`, and `3`.